# como puedo hacer que un algoritmo me permita dentro de un grupo de 20 personas determinar el promedio de edades de hombres, mujeres y de todo un grupo

Tags: java

yo e hecho hasta aca pero no se como hacer la parte de sacar el promedio de  hombres y mujeres por separado.

```
    int i,np,promedio,suma;
            Scanner a=new Scanner(System.in);
            suma=0;
            i=1;
            do{
            System.out.println("DIGITE LA EDAD DE LAS 20 PERSONAS");
            np= a.nextInt();
            i++;
            suma=suma+np;
            }while(i<=20);
            promedio=suma/20;
            System.out.println("EL PROMEDIO DE EDAD ES :" + promedio);
```

Answer (score 0):

Pues mira esta es una solución que te sirve. Pero lo correcto en realidad es crear una clase llamada Persona y guardar las instancias en un ArrayList o algo para que al final  mediante los atributos puedas realizar las operaciones. Te recomiendo que indagar más sobre la programación orientada a objetos.
Sin embargo de momento esto le puede servir:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int cantidad=20;
    int i,np,mujeres=0,hombres=0,sumaMujeres=0,sumaHombres=0;String suma="";String genero="";
    
            Scanner a=new Scanner(System.in);
            i=1;
            do{
            System.out.println("DIGITE LA EDAD DE LA PERSONA"+i);
            np= a.nextInt();
              suma=suma+""+np+";";
            System.out.println("DIGITE EL GÉNERO DE LA PERSONA"+i+" Digite 0 si es mujer o 1 si es hombre");
               genero=genero+""+a.nextInt()+";";
            i++;
          
            }while(i<=cantidad);
            
            String[] divisonGenero=genero.split(";");
            
            String[] divisonSuma=suma.split(";");
            
            for (int j=0;j<cantidad ;j++ ){
                if (Integer.parseInt(divisonGenero[j].toString())==1){
                    hombres++;
                    sumaHombres+=Integer.parseInt(divisonSuma[j].toString());
                } else{
                    mujeres++;
                    sumaMujeres+=Integer.parseInt(divisonSuma[j].toString());
                }
            }
            int promedioHombres=hombres>0?(sumaHombres/hombres):0;
            int promedioMujeres=mujeres>0?(sumaMujeres/mujeres):0;
            
            System.out.println("EL PROMEDIO DE EDAD DE LOS HOMBRES ES DE :" + promedioHombres+
            " Y EL PROMEDIO DE EDAD DE LAS MUJERES ES DE : "+promedioMujeres);
    }
```